# How to use timezoned dates beyond 2038 in Julia?

Tags: timezone, julia

I need to use dates beyond 2038 in Julia. How to do that? Apparently, you cannot use timezoned dates in years after 2038.

The TimeZones.jl's md

https://github.com/JuliaTime/TimeZones.jl/blob/d997abb7398ca8514007d1cbc77a031f721c727b/docs/types.md

gives the following explanation referring to a non-existent link page:

"Alternatively, when using future dates past the year 2038 will result in an error:

```
julia> ZonedDateTime(2039, warsaw)
ERROR: TimeZone Europe/Warsaw does not handle dates on or after 2038-03-28T01:00:00 UTC
 in call at ~/.julia/v0.4/TimeZones/src/timezones/types.jl:146
 in ZonedDateTime at ~/.julia/v0.4/TimeZones/src/timezones/types.jl:260
```

It is possible to have timezones that work beyond 2038 [link] but it since these dates are in the future it is possible the timezone rules may change and will not be accurate."

Comment: There is no person on this planet that can tell you what the time zones will be like in 2038.

Comment: @MattJohnson I am not asking about what the timezones will be like in 2038. Please read my question more carefully! I am asking how to calculate dates in time zones according to today's rules - which Julia does for any year from today to 2038 and also for the past, but not beyond the arbitrary looking 2038.

Comment: `FixedTimeZone` works for any year. So given `warsaw` for example is UTC+0200 for a certain DateTime, you can `ZonedDateTime(2039, FixedTimeZone("+0200"))`. As @MattJohnson said, relying too much on daylight saving time schedules beyond 2038 is not wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct [link](http://timezonesjl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/#far-future-zoneddatetime-with-variabletimezone).

Where it says:

> Due to the internal representation of a VariableTimeZone it is
> infeasible to determine a time zones transitions to infinity. Since
> 2038-01-19T03:14:07 is the last DateTime that can be represented by an
> Int32 (Dates.unix2datetime(typemax(Int32))) it was decided that 2037
> would be the last year in which all transition dates are computed. If
> additional transitions are known to exist after the last transition
> then a cutoff date is specified.
>
> It is important to note that since we are taking about future time
> zone transitions and the rules dictating these transitions are subject
> to change and may not be accurate. **If you still want to work with
> future ZonedDateTime past the default cutoff you can re-compile the
> TimeZone objects and specify the max_year keyword:** *

*Emphasis mine.

```
using TimeZones
    
TimeZones.Olson.compile(max_year=2200)
    
ZonedDateTime(DateTime(2100), TimeZone("Europe/Warsaw"))

>>> 2100-01-01T00:00:00+01:00
```